# How do I make a combobox display a list of dictionaries and act upon the selected value?

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary, serialization, combobox

**C# / Winforms program.**

I have the following class which contains my dictionaries:

```
    public class DictionaryInit
    {
        public Dictionary<int, DictionaryCheckup> C = new Dictionary<int, DictionaryCheckup>()
        {
            {1000, new DictionaryCheckup {theGrouping="C"}},
            {100, new DictionaryCheckup {theGrouping="C"}},
        };
    }
```

Where DictionaryCheckup is a class that get;sets; a string theGrouping.

In the class, I would have letters from C to T, and I wanted to display their values within a combo box. This is what I've tried:

```
        var theDictionaries = new DictionaryInit();
        List<Dictionary<int, DictionaryCheckup>> Dictionaries = new List<Dictionary<int, DictionaryCheckup>> { theDictionaries.C, etc }; 
        cmbDictionList.DataSource = new BindingSource(Dictionaries, null);
```

Running this fills the box with [Collection].

**The process and desired outcome:**

The idea is that, the user first selects a dictionary (C-T) from the combo box and the value gets saved to a variable. I then have the following code that will make use of this:

```
            OFD.ShowDialog();
            var theDict = new DictionaryInit();
            if (OFD.FileName != null)
            {
                using (var stream = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(OFD.FileName)))
                {
                    // Read our JSON from the file
                    var json = stream.ReadToEnd();
                    theDict.E = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int, DictionaryCheckup>>(json);
                    var files = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, DictionaryCheckup>>();
                } 
            }
```

As you can see in my current process, I am explicitly declaring theDict.E. I wish to be able to replace it with a variable I picked up from the combo box earlier, so that I may choose which dictionary I serialize / deserialize.

1. I want to be able to somehow use my DictionaryInit class as the datasource of the combo box.
2. The value selected will determine the dictionary I will serialize in a later method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all DictionaryCheckup  inside DictionaryInit.C have the same letter I would do it like this:

1. Add Letter property to DictionaryInit
2. Bind ComboBox to List
3. Set ComboBox's DisplayMember = "Letter"

Code:

```
    public class DictionaryInit
    {
        public string Letter { get; private set; }

        public DictionaryInit(string letter)
        {
            this.Letter = letter;
            C = new Dictionary<int, DictionaryCheckup>()
            {
                {1000, new DictionaryCheckup {theGrouping=letter}},
                {100, new DictionaryCheckup {theGrouping=letter}},
            };
        }
        public Dictionary<int, DictionaryCheckup> C { get; private set; }
    } 

var list = new List<DictionaryInit>();
list.AddRange(new[]{new DictionaryInit("C"), new DictionaryInit("D")});
cmbDictionList.DataSource = list;
cmbDictionList.DisplayMember = "Letter";
```

Comment: What's the usage of this like if I were to attempt to serialize? Do I simply pull "Letter" ?

Comment: You need any property to display in Combo. You can even get it from dictionary `public string Letter { get {return C.First().Value.theGrouping;} }`

Comment: I managed to get your combobox filling method to work, however, I still don't know how to set the serialization based on the letter selected from the combo box. theDict.E = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int, DictionaryCheckup>>(json);  So, I was wondering how I would replace theDict.E, instead with the found values. E here is a dictionary. The letter I retrieve from the combo box is a string so there is a type mismatch. The example you gave explicitly types C, when it is supposed to simply refer to the selected value.

Comment: If you set `cmbDictionList.DataSource` to `List<DictionaryInit>` and `cmbDictionList.DisplayMember = "Letter"` than `cmbDictionList.SelectedItem` and `cmbDictionList.SelectedValue` would be `DictionaryInit`. The letter C is little confusing because here C is letter from `theGrouping` not property from class `DictionaryInit`